# Calculate the integral without knowing the integrand

Tags: definite-integrals

How can I calculate this integral?

> $$\int_0^{2014} \frac{f(x)}{f(x) + f(2014 - x)}dx$$

Comment: If you know that every function will give same value(maybe by options), then put $f(x)=1$. $$\int_0^{2014}\frac 1 2 dx=1007$$

Comment: Thanks. That's help me. But if I don't know?

Comment: trying it another time for f(x)=x will satisfy **you** that the value is constant. If you just have to submit the answer, then it is an excellent approach(if you can't solve it formally)

Comment: Let
$$
\mathcal{I}_1=\int_0^{2014}\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(2014-x)}dx.
$$
Then, using **property**
$$
\int_b^af(x)\ dx=\int_b^af(a+b-x)\ dx,
$$
the integral turns out to be
$$
\mathcal{I}_2=\int_0^{2014}\frac{f(2014-x)}{f(2014-x)+f(x)}dx.
$$
Since $\mathcal{I}_1=\mathcal{I}_2$, adding $\mathcal{I}_1$ and $\mathcal{I}_2$ yields
$$
2\mathcal{I}=\int_0^{2014}\ dx\quad\Rightarrow\quad \mathcal{I}=1007.
$$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that for $b=2014$, the object you want is

$$W:=\int_0^b \frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(b-x)} dx = 
\int_0^b \frac{f(x)+f(b-x)}{f(x)+f(b-x)} dx - \int_0^b \frac{f(b-x)}{f(x)+f(b-x)} dx\\
= b - \int_0^b \frac{f(b-x)}{f(x)+f(b-x)} dx.$$

Now, by substitution of $t=b-x$,

$$
\int_0^b \frac{f(b-x)}{f(x)+f(b-x)} dx =
-\int_b^0 \frac{f(t)}{f(b-t)+f(t)} dt=\int_0^b \frac{f(t)}{f(t)+f(b-t)}dt.
$$

So plugging that back into the first equation we get $W=b-W$, such that $W=b/2$.

Answer (score 8):

Use substitution $ x' = 2014 - x $, add the two integrals, you get $ 2I = \displaystyle \int_0^{2014} \mathrm{d}x = 2014 \Rightarrow I = 1007 $

Comment: Why that get similar integral?